# iPhone- After resigning first responder on UITextField, can't refocus it

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextfield, first-responder

I have a modal window that's used for searching data from a remote server- it has a UITextField as the titleControl of the navbar for the window, and a tableview filling the window (that displays the results obviously). Now what I want to do is when the user scrolls the tableview, immediately have the textfield lose focus (resign first responder) so that the keyboard dismisses and the user has more room to scroll through the tableview (it stretches down to fill the gap left by the keyboard). Basically the same functionality as when using a UISearchDisplayController (or whatever it's called).

So I have this code for detecting the scroll event of the tableview:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [searchField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Which works fine. However, the issue is that once the user scrolls the table and the textfield loses focus, you can't give focus back to it by tapping on it again. So basically once I call that `[resignFirstResponser]` I can never again bring the keyboard back up and edit the textfield value. Anyone have any idea why? Do I need to explicitly call `[becomeFirstResponder]` on the field somewhere? Because I thought that was handled automatically when the field is tapped?

Also of note- I am calling `[becomeFirstResponder]` on the text field right when the modal window is first called up, so the field is pre-focused. Could that have anything to do with it?

I can post more code if anyone would like, but I don't think I'm doing anything out of the ordinary with the textfield.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the `resignFirstResponder` from a function which will be called everytime you scroll the `UIScrollview`. Hence it does not appear. You need to call resign when the uitextview goes out of focus.

You can do the following. Its a hack:

1. Whenever you focus on the UITextField create a invisible button to overlay your scroll view.
2. Capture the button press event and resign first responder
3. Whenever the uitextfield becomes first responder create the button

This way you will remove the bug, viz calling the method in `scrollViewWillBeginDragging`.
Other option would be to overrite `viewDidAppear` method for the `uiTextField`.

Or you could put your textfield into a different container and handle scrollViewWillBeginDragging by checking which scrollview sent the message.

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work either. Same issue, once I call `[resignFirstResponder]` on the textfield, it no longer is able to gain focus when tapped. In fact, I took out the resignResponder call and just placed it right in the `viewDidAppear` method of the window, and the issue still occurs. So basically it seems as soon as I call the resign method on the textfield, no matter where in the code, it's no longer able to be interacted with. Very annoying...

Comment: No you need to call it at a place where it will be called just once. Dont call in your current's views viewdidappear method. It wont work. Did you create a invisible button and try that approach. Basically its not getting the focus because resignfirstresponder is being called everytime. You can check that by putting a if condition in your code.

Comment: @Praveen: Isn't it necessary to destory the button after capturing the press event?

Answer (score 1):

Did u set a delegate for you searchField? I had the same issue. I popup a model view, and set the text field to be the first responder inside viewDidLoad. Everything works well for the first time. But once I dismiss the modal view controller, and reopen it. my text field cannot be focused anymore.

I found it has something to do with methods of UITextFieldDelegate. Once I remove implementation for methods

```
– textFieldShouldEndEditing:
– textFieldDidEndEditing:
```

everything works well. but don't know why

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing anything with "textFieldShouldEndEditing", like @fengd?

A problem that I had was that I was viewing a modal view, and my "textFieldShouldEndEditing" routine was incorrectly returning "NO" on a specific text field. When my modal got dismissed, I would be unable to tap on any other text-field, presumably because the old text field was still "first responder". Since it can never end editing, it fouls up all other text fields that come after it.

I realize this is 2 yrs after the fact, but maybe someone else might find this useful.